# Four HTML tabs elements, with fade animations, activated by buttons

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, animation

I am pretty new to Javascript and trying to make a really simple tabs element which is just hiding and showing sections depending on which button is clicked. I know that this is a terrible way of writing this, as there is so much repetition, how do I make this code cleaner? (It has to be either Vanilla JS or JQuery as it's for a WordPress site).

```
const tab1 = $('.tab-1');
const tab2 = $('.tab-2');
const tab3 = $('.tab-3');
const tab4 = $('.tab-4');

$('.button-1').click(function() {
    tab1.addClass('active');
    tab2.removeClass('active');
    tab3.removeClass('active');
    tab4.removeClass('active');

    tab1.fadeIn();
    tab2.hide();
    tab3.hide();
    tab4.hide();
});

$('.button-2').click(function() {
    tab1.removeClass('active');
    tab2.addClass('active');
    tab3.removeClass('active');
    tab4.removeClass('active');

    tab1.hide();
    tab2.fadeIn();
    tab3.hide();
    tab4.hide();
});

$('.button-3').click(function() {
    tab1.removeClass('active');
    tab2.removeClass('active');
    tab3.fadeIn('active');
    tab4.removeClass('active');

    tab1.hide();
    tab2.hide();
    tab3.fadeIn();
    tab4.hide();
});

$('.button-4').click(function() {
    tab1.removeClass('active');
    tab2.removeClass('active');
    tab3.removeClass('active');
    tab4.addClass('active');

    tab1.hide();
    tab2.hide();
    tab3.hide();
    tab4.fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Short review to make this more DRY

- Review the documentation on https://api.jquery.com/toggle/, this often helps with code like this
- Know that you can select multiple id's by separting selectors with a comma in jQuery
- You can chain jQuery commands, which can lead to either more or less readable code, it's an art. In this code, I feel there is not enough chaining
  Knowing this, you can rewrite to something like this;

  ```
  const tab1 = $('.tab-1');
  const tab2 = $('.tab-2');
  const tab3 = $('.tab-3');
  const tab4 = $('.tab-4');
  const allTabs = $('.tab-1,.tab-2,.tab-3,.tab-4');

  $('.button-1').click(function() {
      allTabs.removeClass('active').hide();
      tab1.addClass('active').fadeIn();
  });

  $('.button-2').click(function() {
      allTabs.removeClass('active').hide();
      tab2.addClass('active').fadeIn();
  });

  $('.button-3').click(function() {
    allTabs.removeClass('active').hide();
    tab3.addClass('active').fadeIn();
  });

  $('.button-4').click(function() {
    allTabs.removeClass('active').hide();
    tab4.addClass('active').fadeIn();
  });
  ```